# Curl no working in PHP CLI SAPI

Tags: php, curl, command-line-interface

My php curl script does not recognize curl_init(); as a resource lots of errors follow. bellow is the cli output to clarify.

NOTE I am aware of the $url issue but I am trying to solve one problem at a time( however help with either issue will be appreciated:)):

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: url in /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php on line 9
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php:0
PHP   2. website->exec() /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php:29
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: ch in /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php on line 18
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php:0
PHP   2. website->exec() /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php:29
PHP   3. website->info() /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php:11
PHP Warning:  curl_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php on line 18
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php:0
PHP   2. website->exec() /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php:29
PHP   3. website->info() /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php:11
PHP   4. curl_error() /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php:18
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: ch in /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php on line 19
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php:0
PHP   2. website->exec() /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php:29
PHP   3. website->info() /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php:11
PHP Warning:  curl_getinfo() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php on line 19
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php:0
PHP   2. website->exec() /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php:29
PHP   3. website->info() /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php:11
PHP   4. curl_getinfo() /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php:19
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: ch in /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php on line 15
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php:0
PHP   2. website->close() /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php:30
PHP Warning:  curl_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php on line 15
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php:0
PHP   2. website->close() /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php:30
PHP   3. curl_close() /var/www/Jobbotback/getsite.php:15
```

Here is the code being executed:

```
<?php
class website {
    function seturl($param) {
        $url = $param;
    }
    function exec() {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $site = curl_exec($ch);
        $this->info();
        return $site;
    }
    function close() {
        curl_close($ch);
    }
    function info() {
        if(!curl_error($ch)) {
            $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
            echo $info;
        } else {
            $error = curl_error($ch);
            echo $error;
        }
    }
}
$test = new website;
$test -> seturl('www.google.com');
$content = $test -> exec();
$test ->close();
echo $content;
```

What really bothers me is the fact that `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` returns nothing when I enter `/curl` in vim, I tried to look up on web what should php.ini look like but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to variables in your class methods that don't exist.  You define `$ch` in `exec`, and close it in `close`, but you are not storing a reference to `$ch` at the class level.  Add a `$ch` as a property to your class and then change all the references to `$ch` to `$this->ch`.  The same is true for $url.

```
class website {
  private $ch;
  private $url;

  function seturl($param) {
    $this->url = $param;
  }
  function exec() {
    $this->ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt( $this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
    $site = curl_exec($this->ch);
    $this->info();
    return $site;
  }
  function close() {
    curl_close($this->ch);
  }
  function info() {
    if(!curl_error($this->ch)) {
        $info = curl_getinfo($this->ch);
        echo $info;
    } else {
        $error = curl_error($this->ch);
        echo $error;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Short and Straight to the point answer, just what I needed. Thank you